# Where is the option to set maxParticipantDuration in JavaScript SDK?

Tags: twilio-video

I used the backend to obtain the Access Token, and connect (auto-create) to a room like this -

```
room = await Video.connect(accessToken, {
    video: true,
    audio: true,
    name: "Room1",
});
```

I looked at ConnectOptions and I don't see anywhere that I can set the maxParticipantDuration for the room. Does anyone know where to set this? I know this can be set if the room is created using Rest API. Is this option not available if using the JavaScript SDK?

[Rest API to Set maxParticipantDuration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/configure-maximum-participant-duration#:%7E:text=Twilio%20Video%20Rooms%20allow%20you,a%20Room%20is%2024%20hours.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No option in JavaScript SDK for `the maximum Participant duration`

From the [manual](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/configure-maximum-participant-duration#:%7E:text=Twilio%20Video%20Rooms%20allow%20you,a%20Room%20is%2024%20hours.)

> If you wish to configure the maximum Participant duration for you
> Video Rooms, you can do so in two ways: via the **Twilio REST API**, or
> via the **Twilio Console**.

BY API

```js
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.video.v1.rooms
               .create({
                  maxParticipantDuration: 86400,
                  uniqueName: 'My Video Room'
                })
               .then(room => console.log(room.sid));
```

[image]

By Twilio Console
[image]

So no option for `maximum Participant duration` in `ConnectOptions` [here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video.js/blob/master/tsdef/types.d.ts#L192) from `JavaScript SDK`

```js
export interface ConnectOptions {
  audio?: boolean | CreateLocalTrackOptions| CreateLocalAudioTrackOptions;
  automaticSubscription?: boolean;
  bandwidthProfile?: BandwidthProfileOptions;
  dominantSpeaker?: boolean;

  /**
   * @deprecated use enableDscp
   */
  dscpTagging?: boolean;
  enableDscp?: boolean;

  /**
   * @deprecated use Video.Logger
   */
  loggerName?: string;
  eventListener?: EventListener;
  iceServers?: Array<RTCIceServer>;
  iceTransportPolicy?: RTCIceTransportPolicy;
  insights?: boolean;
  maxAudioBitrate?: number | null;
  maxVideoBitrate?: number | null;
  name?: string | null;
  networkQuality?: boolean | NetworkQualityConfiguration;
  notifyWarnings?: Array<NotifyWarning>;
  region?: string;
  preferredAudioCodecs?: Array<AudioCodec | AudioCodecSettings | OpusCodecSettings>;
  preferredVideoCodecs?: Array<VideoCodec | VideoCodecSettings | VP8CodecSettings> | VideoEncodingMode;

  /**
   * @deprecated use Video.Logger.
   */
  logLevel?: LogLevel | LogLevels;

  tracks?: Array<LocalTrack | MediaStreamTrack>;
  video?: boolean | CreateLocalTrackOptions;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to come up with a solution over the weekend by first creating the Room using Rest API, and passing the Room name to the client. It is a bit tricky because I have to check if the Room already exists by calling another API, but I got it working.

Comment: I glad to hear to address by REST API your problem.